# Spring Integration Http Inbound Gateway Request Logging

Tags: spring-integration

Hi I am currently using Spring Integration 4.0.3.I have a requirement of logging the actual request which are coming to the Http Inbound Gateways.The request are to be logged before they are converted into a message by the Http Inbound Messaging Gateway and sent to the gateway request channel.This is how I am trying to achieve this .

1. Configured a aop pointcut on the HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway class handleRequest method.
2. Configured a custom method Interceptor as an advice and configured the pointcut to execute this advice in the aop config.
3. In the MethodInterceptor I am retreiving the Request and Response object and logging the request.

But it seems whenever I am applying the aop on handleRequest method the dispatcher servlet is unable to find the handler for any of the url mapping used by all of my http inbound gateways.

I know the same can be achieved through configuring filters in web.xml but I am just curious why this is happening....Please help ...

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can't proxy `HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway#handleRequest` because it is `final`.

From other side there is no reason to do so complex AOP work for that logging stuff.

`HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway` populates `RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()` as `EvaluatationContext` variable, so you can put it to `MessageHeader` and use anywhere in downstream flow:

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway path="/foo" request-channel="requestChannel">
     <int-http:header name="requestAttributes" expression="#requestAttributes"/>
</int-http:inbound-gateway>

<publish-subscribe-channel id="requestChannel"/>

<logging-channel-adapter channel="requestChannel" 
                expression="headers.requestAttributes.request"/>
```